# custom login page not working after authorizeRequest() deprecation - spring boot & security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-thymeleaf

I am trying to replace a simple thymeleaf login page with the default one. The problem is it is not working as expected. I am getting the authorization requred as an alert for example. I am providing the screenshots and codes for the security in which authorizeRequest() and antMatchers are not used anymore.

[I am getting this alert instead of getting the replaced login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aehd.png)

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class HospitalSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
        
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/").authenticated()
        .requestMatchers("/mylogin").permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/mylogin").loginProcessingUrl("/mylogin").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider())
        .httpBasic()
        ;
        
        return http.build();
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService detailsService() {
        
        return new HospitalUserDetailsServiceer();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService());
                
                return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

myLogin.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome to HealthMe Application!</title>
 <link th:href="@{/css/cssLogin.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jsLogin.js}"></script>
 </head>
<body>

<form th:action="@{/mylogin}" method="post">

Username = <input name="username" type="text"> <br>
Password = <input name="password" type="password"> <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I handled the "/mylogin" path call by:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class HospitalMVCconfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/mylogin").setViewName("myLogin");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have httpBasic at the end?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is one of my tries to solve the problem! I removed the httpBasic and basic authorization is gone. But the problem is still there. the custom login page is shown but it does not redirect the request to the default path which is "/" after successful authentication! also, logout is not working despite I handled the "/logout" path to redirect to the login page. The endpoints remain accessible after logging out! thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Checkout the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html

Comment: What version of spring security are you using?

Comment: This might help https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_permit_forward_when_using_spring_mvc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @SimonMartinelli and Marcus, your links helped me solve the problem. For the logout problem, I handled the logout by creating an instance of AntPathRequestMatcher("my logout path") object and using it in logoutRequestMatcher. For the login side, removing the httpBasic declaration, helped me.

Comment: Please add your solution as the answer. It maybe helpful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem and put the final code here:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeHttpRequests(t ->
                t.anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            )
    .formLogin(form ->
            form
            .loginPage("/mylogin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/mylogin")
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            .permitAll()
                )
    .logout(out ->
            out.logoutRequestMatcher(new 
    AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll()
            )
    
    .authenticationProvider(authProvider()
     );
    return http.build();
}
```

where the successful handler method is as follows:

```
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
    return simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
}
```